# Passing parameters to a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm trying to figure out how to pass my callback additional parameters. So far I have the following code.

```
$("#refine_mp_type").change(function(){
    var mp_type = $(this).val();
    var country_id = $('#refine_country').val();
    var dropdown = $('#refine_grade').find('select');
    getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type, populateGradesDropdown);
});

function getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type, callback){
    display_wait_dialog ("Please Wait", "Loading grades...");
    $.ajax(
    {
        //do ajax
    })
    .done(function(data){
        callback(data);
    })
    .fail(//do something)
    .always(//do something);
}

populateGradesDropdown(data){
    //populate the dropdown with the returned data
}
```

My thoughts so far on how to achieve this are:

1. I could set the dropdown variable to global scope and access it that way(Will pollute global scope).
2. I could pass the dropdown element to getMPTypeGrades function and then pass it to the callback function. (I want to keep getMPTypeGrades as generic as possible. I don't know if I'll always be passing a callback that accepts a JQuery element.)

What is the best method for passing the JQuery element and the Ajax response as parameters for my callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind dropdown to callback function:

```
$("#refine_mp_type").change(function(){
    var mp_type = $(this).val();
    var country_id = $('#refine_country').val();
    var dropdown = $('#refine_grade').find('select');
    getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type, populateGradesDropdown.bind(null, dropdown));
});
```

Then

```
populateGradesDropdown(dropdown, data){
    //populate the dropdown with the returned data
}
```

Comment: when you set the `dropdown` as the first argument of the bind, you can access it in `populateGradesDropdown` with the `this` keyword.

Comment: Yep, but `populateGradesDropdown` might be universal function and may use its context. But you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) and [jQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Basically you create a deferred object with a pending state and return it to the caller. `jQuery when` executes the callback function only when the deferred object has been resolved or rejected. When your ajax request is finished, `.resolve` or `.reject` will be called. This will trigger the callback method in the caller.

I haven't tested this code, but it should work more or less.

```
$("#refine_mp_type").change(function() {
    var mp_type = $(this).val();
    var country_id = $('#refine_country').val();
    var dropdown = $('#refine_grade').find('select');
    $.when(getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type)).then(function(result) {
       //populate dropdown
    });
});

function getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type) {
    var def = $.Deferred();   
    display_wait_dialog ("Please Wait", "Loading grades...");
    $.ajax(
    {
        //do ajax
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        def.resolve(data);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        def.reject(err);
    })
    .always(function() {
        hide_wait_dialog();
    });
    return def;
}
```

Comment: linking is good, but give a little explanation about the `deffered`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing a callback (which can create a 'pyramid' code of callbacks), you should just return the deferred ajax object in `getMPTypeGrades`. You can then just use the standard `.done()/.then()` functions within the change handler:

```
$("#refine_mp_type").change(function(){
    var mp_type = $(this).val();
    var country_id = $('#refine_country').val();
    var dropdown = $('#refine_grade').find('select');
    getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type).then(populateGradesDropdown);
});

function getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type){
    display_wait_dialog ("Please Wait", "Loading grades...");
    return $.ajax(
    {
        //do ajax
    })
    .fail(//do something)
    .always(//do something);
}

populateGradesDropdown(data){
    //populate the dropdown with the returned data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the original dropdown variable in the callback function body:

```
var dropdown = /*whatever*/;
getMPTypeGrades(country_id, mp_type, function(data) {
    populateGradesDropdown(data, dropdown);
});

$.ajax({
}).done(function(data){
    callback(data);
})

function populateGradesDropdown(data, dropdown){
    alert("data=" + data);
    alert("dropdown=" + dropdown);
}
```